# Android webrtc building failed

Tags: android, webrtc

Webrtc build stops at `obj/webrtc/audio/audio_tests/audio_send_stream_unittest.o`.

Can anyone suggest why does that happen?

I have followed [this](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) for webrtc building.

Comment: What error message do you get? Does it point at some particular line?

Comment: No error , just stop everytime at obj/webrtc/audio/audio_tests/audio_send_stream_unittest.o   . Then no progress....

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: It worked for me when I build it release mode ... 
gn gen out/Default --args='is_debug=false'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this might be the perfect answer but disabling debugging in Ninja worked for me.

*Debugging disabled*

```
$ gn gen out/Debug_arm64 --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm64" is_debug=”false”'
$ ninja -C out/Debug_arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

Small fix in cutiehulk2329 answer:

```
$ gn gen out/Debug_arm64 --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm64" is_debug=false'
```

So `is_debug=false` without quotes